# Why in java the substring of last index is not equal to ""?

Tags: java, string, substring

For example 

`System.out.println("a".substring(1) == "");`

will return `false`.

However, it does return an instance of `String`such that `println` will display nothing. What is it and how to detect it, then?

Comment: here I can see a basic mistake, you can use ("a".substring(1)).equals("")

Comment: `System.out.println("a".substring(1).isEmpty());`